# Go to the next page - button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I have a folder called Portfolio, and inside that folder there are .HTML pages for each project. 
Now, on each Project page there is are three buttons, one is Go Back, and one is Next Project.
I have managed to get the Go Back button work - and send the user to the Portfolio main Page.

The question is, what is the best solution to make the Next Project button work? - and send the user to the next project page (the .html file that is next to the current open .html file).

Hope my question is clear.

Comment: Your Next Project link will be dynamic ?

Comment: Got any server-side scripting available (e.g. PHP)?

Comment: <a href="w3schools.com">Next Project</a>

Comment: On page load, check to see if there is a next available project, if so, load up the button and assign the redirect, else, make the button disabled since there isn't one.

Comment: [this may be helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7022058/javascript-read-files-in-folder)

Comment: @Jonathan `<a href="AnywhereEXCEPTw3schools.com">Next Project</a>`

Comment: Is there anyway to do this using JavaScript or HTML? I don't want to manually link it.

Comment: How does that work @Grant Thomas? AnywhereEXCEPT ?

Comment: >Is there anyway to do this using JavaScript or HTML? I don't want to manually link it –– 

I don't think you really know what you're talking about.

Comment: I am new to this, that's why I am asking mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access the filesystem using the technologies from the tags. (There is [FileSystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-dir-move-rename), but it can't get access to any particular directory, but a sandboxed one.)

You will need to use some back-end language (like [Ruby](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/ruby-for-newbies-working-with-directories-and-files/)) or a static site generator (like [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/)). Alternatively, you could put a link to the next file manually: `<a href="next-file.html">Next</a>`.